# How do I write the document's ID into the document itself using Cloud Functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When a new user is created, I want to have a cloud function insert a new record into my `users` collection. I tried doing so with the code below but when I checked my logs it gave this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'resourcePath' of undefined
> at doc (/workspace/node_modules...)

The reason I want to do it this way is because I want to be able to store the document ID within the document itself. This will serve as a "rowpointer" like in SQL - a unique way to identify the row in the collection.

**Code:**

```
exports.newUserSignup = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  console.log('user created', user.email, user.uid);
  const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc
  return doc(user.uid).set({
    createDate: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    modifiedDate: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    username: 'blah',
    email: user.email,    
    stat: 1,
    uid: user.uid,
    rowpointer: doc().id,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, but have a few syntax errors in your code. This should be closer:

```
exports.newUserSignup = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  console.log('user created', user.email, user.uid);
  const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc();
  return doc.set({
    createDate: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    modifiedDate: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    username: 'blah',
    email: user.email,    
    stat: 1,
    uid: user.uid,
    rowpointer: doc.id,
  });
});
```

I highly recommend keeping the reference docs handy when you're having trouble with this type of exercise, as I found the problem pretty quickly when looking at [`CollectionReference.doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) and [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference)

Comment: Great tip, I actually forgot to open them today.

This looks like it worked but for the 2 date fields it wrote .sv: "timestamp" instead of the actual timestamp: https://imgur.com/xaNx7rq  

Do you know why it might have done this?

Comment: Not right away, but that also seems a separate issue. I recommend opening a new question for that problem, and also show how you import `admin` there.

Comment: Ah, I just spotted it: you're using `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` and it should be `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.